# stimulus diable auto log methods fired for one controller

Tags: stimulusjs

I try disable auto log info abount all controllers.

this code

```
this.application.debug = false;
```

disable for all controllers is possible to disable in one ?

i also found this

```
static get config() {
        return {
            debug: false,
        }
    }
```

but this not working

Answer (score 0):

Good morning. You can try to access into "\node_modules@symfony\stimulus-bridge\dist\index.js" and find the function startStimulusApp. If you do not want debug, set application.debug on false.

Comment: i want debug but not all, i have many controllers so debug is to large for clean reading. ready not good that i cannot debug selected or one controller...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).